# Bash script stops after 1 file

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, bam

I'm trying to run a bioinformatics command line tool on all .bam files in a directory. This is what I'm using:

```
#!/bin/sh

reference='/path/Homo_sapiens_assembly19.fasta'

for f in *.bam
do 
    base_name=${f%.bam}
    java -jar /ppath/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -R $reference \
   -T ASEReadCounter \
   -o $base_name.csv \
   -I $f \
   -sites $base_name.vcf \
   -U ALLOW_N_CIGAR_READS \
   -minDepth 10 \
   --minMappingQuality 10 \
   --minBaseQuality 2
done;
```

The problem is that the loop stops after iterating over the first bam file. I will eventually like this to go over a set of 2000 .bam files, and I don't want to have to enter them all manually (it will take >30 hours).

Comment: How do you know it stops after the first file?

Comment: I only get 1 output file, and in the terminal, I only see a call to the first .bam file ie. substitute base_name and $f for sample1.

@John1024: No the script does not. That was a formatting error. I know that the script works in the sense that it gives me exactly what I want for 1 bam in the directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "call to the first .bam file"?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The directory has files named sampleN.bam/sampleN.vcf for N = 1,2....

I see that it executes the desired command for sample1.bam, sample1.vcf, but not for any subsequent (bam,vcf) pair.

Comment: How do you see that it executes the command?

Comment: Btw. `bash` != `sh`

Comment: @melpomene when the software tool runs, it displays the entire command:

Comment: So ... have you attempted any debugging?

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks! Honestly, I didn't even know how to change directories until Monday of last week. All very new for me.

Comment: @melpomene I'm not quite sure what to attempt. It took me a few hours of fiddling just to get the desired output. I've seen some people iterate over files using a file list. Maybe I'll try that.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: There's also a handy shell script tool online you might find useful: http://shellcheck.net

Comment: So the shellcheck.net said "Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting" whenever $ was used in the script. I'm now running it with the double quotes around those regions.

Comment: Adding double quotes to those regions didn't change anything. Still only ran once.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. Basically, I was running this as a test so that when I need to do it later this week, I'm ready to do it. The problem is, I only have 1 bam file, the second is a copy. When I copied it, it was copied as a text file with bam extension. When I remove the original bam file, I get an error where no .bams are input into the software. I will download and clean another bam file to test.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

reference='/path/Homo_sapiens_assembly19.fasta'

for f in $(ls ./*.bam); do
    base_name=${f%.bam} 
    #base_name=$(basename ${f})  # alternatively you can use this
    java -jar /ppath/GenomeAnalysisTK.jar -R ${reference} \
   -T ASEReadCounter \
   -o ${base_name}.csv \
   -I ${f} \
   -sites ${base_name}.vcf \
   -U ALLOW_N_CIGAR_READS \
   -minDepth 10 \
   --minMappingQuality 10 \
   --minBaseQuality 2
done;
```

I suspect your `-o $base_name.csv` was looking for a variable called `basename.csv` and not `basename`, thus overwriting the output file, making it appear as if only a single bam file was processed. This should be easy to fix by calling your bash variables by using `${basename}`, before extending them with a suffix.

Comment: The original script ended up working. The problem was that my second bam file in the directory was actually a txt file. I ran it again with two genuine bam files, and it worked.